Why are there 2 dative elements in this sentence?
I came across the following sentence online:

Wähl die fünf Sätze aus, in denen trennbaren Verben vorkommen

I can understand why the dative relative pronoun denen is used - because of the in in front of it. But why trennbaren Verben, which is also dative? The sentence can be paraphrased in the following way:

Trennbare Verben kommen in den fünf Sätzen vor.

so trennbare Verben should be nominative instead of dative. Which part in my reasoning is wrong? Thanks in advance.

I’m voting to close this question because it's just a typo and therefore of no interest for other users.

You came across a typo, it has to be "trennbare Verben".
